# Actionscript 3 - How to Move Between Maps/Levels

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash-builder, flash

I have a top down game and i just want to know how to make it so when the character hits the right side he will go to the right map/level.  I feel like this is a basic necessary part of a lot of games so i don't know how nobody has a tutorial or guide for this.  I would be so grateful for anyone that can help.  I know this isn't alot of info so just comment if you want more info.  Basically just how can you make an almost rpg style movement between maps?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your last question:  [Action Script 3 Moving Between Rooms/Levels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992497/action-script-3-moving-between-rooms-levels)

Comment: @batman Kinda but i thought id make a new one and make it less complicated.  On the other question i wanted to know a lot more.  This one i just want to know how to change rooms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Batman stated in the comments of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992497/action-script-3-moving-between-rooms-levels), this is a pretty broad question and you have multiple ways to accomplish this.

I will tell you about one possible approach, or rather, what you need to learn to accomplish something like this. As a side note, you seem to be a beginner, so maybe you should try to do easier stuff first, because this is a fairly complex topic.

- You need a 2 Dimensional Array that contains rooms (or rather, the data of the rooms), which in effect is something like a table
- each of these rooms has a `row` and a `column` to identify their position
- You need to be able to tell in which position the player has left a room, `left`, `right`, `up`, `down`
- You need to be aware in which room the Player is located (through the aforementioned `row` and `column` ids of the room)
- According to the direction of the player, you need to load the room with the corresponding `row` and `column` identifiers. For example, if you move to the `left`, you should decrease the row identifier of the player location. If you move `up`, you should decrease (depends on the orientation of your table) the column identifier and so on. These updated variables will tell you which room you need to show next

Comment: Thanks a lot man!  Batman told me that but i have no idea to make the question less broad...  i have created a game and need to be able to move rooms :/  Ill learn all those topics and try to see what i come up with!

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad I was able to help you in some way. Regarding your project, I would suggest looking into [Random Dungeon Generation](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Dungeon-Building_Algorithm) (one example of such a algorithm) next.

Comment: I might end up using that algorithm. right now im using my own way of randomizing it.  I have a question if you know how to answer it.I have the ROOMS[][] array and at the beginning it randomly puts blocks and such in these rooms.  Im trying to make it check to see if there is not a room(ex. not a room at [1][1]) and if there isnt then change the wall image to block that exit by using ROOM[currentRow][currentCol].gotoAndStop(5);Right now im doing it by checking if ROOM[currentRow+1][currentCol] == null and this works for some walls it doesnt for others, sometimes it outputs a term is undefined

Comment: sorry if that's hard to understand, i didn't have enough characters lol   If you think you could help i could make another question and put some of the code and such on there.

Comment: Sure, go ahead and ask another question separately.

Comment: I asked another question, if you know how to do it, id be grateful as hell lol